# What word is used for an enemy in a Video Game?

Tags: words, video-games

What is the most common Japanese word to use when referring to any kind of enemy in a video game. I know the word モンスター is common for non-human enemies, but is there just a general term for any kind of enemy? Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Native speaker here.  敵{てき}キャラ might be what you are looking for.  You could use 敵 if you wanted to but that word is so general that it is used in a war in real life as well. 敵 just does not give off the fun feeling that　敵キャラ and モンスター do for the player.

Comment: Thank you for confirming that. It makes complete sense now. n__n

Comment: Sorry, is that reading かたき or てき?

Comment: When I hear かたき I think 仇, actually...

Answer (score 10):

As far as I know, the most general term for an opponent or enemy is 敵【てき】. This applies to enemies in games, as well.

Comment: Thank you. After a few Google searches for game enemies, it seems like 敵 is almost always followed by キャラ like 敵キャラ. キャラ being an abbreviation for キャラクター or character. Is using 敵 by itself just as acceptable?

Comment: I disagree for the reason I gave in my answer.

Comment: To his credit, 敵キャラ is what you would say *outside* the context of the game in specific reference to it as a type of character. Inside the game they wouldn't say 「敵キャラをやっつけてください」

Comment: I agree with ssb, we say [敵]{てき} when actually playing the game, eg ほらそこ、敵！/敵が来た！/ここ、敵多い！rather than ほらそこ、敵キャラ！/敵キャラが来た！/ここ、敵キャラ多い！

Comment: @ssb: Clearly characters in a game do not refer to _their_ enemy as an “enemy in a game” unless it is a metafictional reference, but I do not think that this is what this question is about.  That said, as ちょこれーと stated, we sometimes use also 敵 to mean 敵キャラ.  As far as I can imagine, this happens either (1) when the meaning is clear from the context or (2) when the speaker feels that he/she is inside the game.  In the case of (2), the speaker is essentially acting as a character in the game.